# FBX 6100 to 7100

Tags: blender, fbx

Ok, So I have been trying to upload an FBX 6100 model into blender and been having a little bit of a problem with uploading. I have tried converting the model into other file types and it seems to lose some resolution of it, essentially becoming worse. Is it possible to bring the file from 6100 to 7100 in any way? Autodesk converter has not been of any help either...so I am kinda in a bind.

Answer (score 3):

If you have windows 10, you can convert old FBX files by [loading them into PAINT 3D](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/paint-3d/9nblggh5fv99) and then choose:

> menu > export file > FBX

This allowed me to successfully import [this FBX 6100 low poly car](https://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/552663) into blender 2.79.

Comment: This was an out-of-the-box solution that actually worked when so many suggestions (and the AutoDesk converters) did not!  Thank you!